# How to get out of infinite loop of Sudoku code if the Sudoku can't be solved?

Tags: python, python-3.x, exception, infinite-loop, sudoku

I've created a code that solves sudoku using the elimination method, and it works on all properly formatted sudoku puzzles. However, I have been given a test case where the puzzle is unsolvable, and thus causes my code to run infinitely. I have created an exception SudokuUnsolvable that I need to raise in this case, but I don't know how to implement it into my code.

```
class SudokuUnsolvable(Exception):
    pass

def sudokuSolver (s, strategies) :
    counter=0
    while solved(s)==False:
        for strategy in strategies:
            applyStrategy(strategy, s)
        
        if applyStrategy(strategy, s)==False:
            break
        counter+=1

    return s
```

There are a lot of smaller codes for functions I've used (like the applyStrategy code)

```
def applyStrategy(strategy, s) :
    r=0
    n=0
    new=0
    counter=0
    for row in range(len(s)):
        for num in range(len(s[row])):
            if s[row][num]!=0:
                pass
            else:
                new=elimination(num, row, s)
                if s[row][num]!=new:
                    s[row][num]=new
                    counter+=1 
    
    if counter==0:
        return False
    else:
        return True
```

It seems that the if statement in sudokuSolver automatically exits the loop if the sudoku stops changing, so an exception is never able to be raised. Is there anyway for me to raise the exception within this code if the algorithm fails to solve the puzzle?

Answer (score 0):

I would validate sudoku beforehand, but you could just add `if counter>MAX_STRATEGY_COUNT: break` to your code.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that `s` is your sudoku board. You can check if it's changed at all after all the strategies have been applied. If it hasn't, you know you can't solve it anymore.

You can do it by keeping the original around and comparing it at the end of the loop. Or you can use some flag which is reset at the beginning and then set if you make any change.